# WinRT Image XAML is not loaded after download

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am doing a Windows Store app for Win 8.1 (WinRT). One of the pages of the app is an address book. In certain scenarios the app receives push notifications. One of them could be that a certain contact has a new picture. When the app handles the push notification (NOT the background task for push notification, which works fine), it downloads the new image from a link specified in the push notification and fires an event that should update the UI with the new image. The image is stored in the LocalFolder (ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder). After the event is fired, the UI is updated, but now without any picture for the respective contact. After restarting the app, the picture appears. While the app is running, I also opened Windows Explorer to see if the file is downloaded and it is. One peculiar thing is that until the app is restarted (or stopped), there is no thumbnail for the new picture. I really cannot figure out why do I need to restart the app in order for the picture to appear. Images are quite small around 40-60KB. The update is achieved by resetting the ItemsSource which is binded to a property which raises PropertyChanged. It can be seen that the ItemsSource is set, because of short blinking, but now the item, which got updated, has no picture.

Here is the code that does the download:

```
public async Task GetContactImage(String[] pushContent)
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var contactImagesfolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync("ContactImages", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // Increase the max buffer size for the response so we don't get an exception with so many web sites
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(pushContent[2]);

        StorageFile picture = await contactImagesfolder.CreateFileAsync(pushContent[2].Split('/').Last(), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        IRandomAccessStream pictureStream = await picture.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(pictureStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
        writer.WriteBytes(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
        await writer.StoreAsync();
        writer.DetachStream();
        await pictureStream.FlushAsync();

        pictureStream.Dispose();
        writer.Dispose();

        Dal.Instance.UpdateContactImage(pushContent[1], pushContent[2]);
    }
```

The respective XAML, which is a DataTemplate for a ListView (duh):

```
<Image Height="128" Width="128" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource contactImageConverter}}" />
```

And the converter I use to set the Source property:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var contact = value as Contact;
        String imagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/UnknownMan.png";
        if (contact != null)
        {
            if (contact.Image != null && contact.Image != "" && contact.Image != "Unknow_man.png")
            {
                imagePath = "ms-appdata:///local/ContactImages/" + contact.Image.Split('/').Last();                    
            }
        }

        return imagePath;
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Although there is automatic type conversion from string to ImageSource: how does it behave if your converter returns a BitmapImage instead of just the image path string? Something like `return new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath));`.

Comment: Is the new URI the same as the old one? If it is the same and there is a little blinking, it may be that the first request is cached. Can you get NETMON or Fiddler traces of the HTTP headers?

Comment: How to debug: break the problem into smaller parts. Substitute each step in the chain of action with something you _know_ works. E.g. embed a bitmap resource or load from a file a bitmap to set at runtime, and see if you can get _that_ to work. If it does, then you can focus on the retrieval of the other bitmap; if it doesn't, then you can focus on the setting of the bitmap. As is, there's too little information here for someone to answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you all for your help, but the cause for the problem turned out to be how I save the file to the file system. I will post the solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the method of saving the file to the file system created some kind of handle or so, which would not allow the app to load the image. What I did is to change the approach of saving the file.

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder contactImagesfolder = await folder.CreateFolderAsync("ContactImages", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFile picture = await contactImagesfolder.CreateFileAsync(imageURL.Split('/').Last(), CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
// Increase the max buffer size for the response so we don't get an exception with so many web sites
httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(imageURL);

var responseByteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(picture, responseByteArray);

Dal.Instance.UpdateContactImage(contactID, imageURL);
```